# Error in the expression rdlc

Tags: rdlc

Im getting error for the below expression in rdlc. what is causing error

```
=IIf(Fields!Name.Value Like "PL*","STREET INTERSECTION","STREET SEGMENT")
```

[image]

the requirement is the value of the text box should be dynamic depending on the item Name("Name" field). If the item Name starts with PL, this value should be "STREET INTERSECTION" if name starts with PS , this Value should be "STREET SEGMENT".

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

SSRS supports VBA functionality rather SQL function / syntax.

```
=IIf(Fields!Name.Value.IndexOf("PL") >= 0,"STREET INTERSECTION","STREET SEGMENT")
```